# Call API and redirect to next page with same click ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have created a button on ReactJS that is supposed to submit and send the input username and password to backend, validate that account with those credentials exists and if it does, route the user to the products page.

My issue is that I have to click twice for this to happen. 1st click checks if username and password `isValid` and then 2nd click redirects to the products page if `true`. However, I would like this to be done with one click.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import './Home.css';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';

function Home() {

  const [isValid, setValidation] = useState([]);
  const [user, setUser] = useState('');
  const [pw, setPw] = useState('');

  function setDetails(){
    setUser(document.getElementById("username").value);
    setPw(document.getElementById("password").value);
  }

  useEffect(() => {

    let reqBody = {username: user, password: pw};

    const fetchValidation = async () => {

      const data = await fetch(`https://example.com/validate`, {method: 'POST', headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json'}, body:JSON.stringify(reqBody)});
  
      const isValid = await data.json();
      setValidation(isValid);
      console.log(isValid);
    };
    fetchValidation();
  }, [user, pw]);

  let logInLink;

  if (isValid){
    logInLink = "/products";
  }else{
    logInLink = "/";
  }

  return (
    <div className="Background">
      <p className ="HomeTitle">Product App</p>
      <input type = "text" id = "username" placeholder="username"/>
      <input type = "password" id = "password" placeholder="password"/>
      <Link to={logInLink} className="LogInButton" onClick={event => setDetails()}>Log in</Link>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

UPDATED:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import './Home.css';

function Home() {

  const [isValid, setIsValid] = useState(false);
  const [user, setUser] = useState('');
  const [pw, setPw] = useState('');
  const fetchValidation = async () => {
    const reqBody = {username: user, password: pw};
    const data = await fetch(`https://example.com/validate`, {method: 'POST', headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json'}, body:JSON.stringify(reqBody)});
    const isValid = await data.json();
    setIsValid(isValid);
    console.log(isValid);
  };

  function validate(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    fetchValidation();
  }

  function setUsername(){
    setUser(document.getElementById("username").value);
  }

  function setPassword(){
    setPw(document.getElementById("password").value);
  }

  if (isValid){
    return (
    <Redirect to="/products"/>
    )
  }else{ 
    return (
      <div className="Background">
      <p className ="HomeTitle">Product App</p>
      <form onSubmit = {validate}>
        <input type = "text" id = "username" placeholder="username" onChange = {setUsername}/>
        <input type = "password" id = "password" placeholder="password" onChange = {setPassword}/>
        <input type = "submit" value="Log In"/>
      </form>
    </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Home;
```

Comment: This is not the way React is expected to be used. Normally, if you need to access DOM elements, you're probably doing it bad.

Comment: Besides that, with the examples you posted is very difficult to follow code execution and debug it. Please, publish full component if it's simple enough to exemplify the error, or a simplified version, removing all the parts unneeded for this.

Comment: For example: show code used for `fetch`ing the user/pw validation, the definition of `setUser` and `setPw`, where each code block you published is in, etc

Comment: Hi @emi, will share my entire component when I get back home

Comment: @emi, updated my post with the full code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to redirect after user validation:

```js
  return isValid
   ? <Redirect to="/products" />
   : (
    <div className="Background">
      <p className="HomeTitle">Product App</p>
      <input type="text" id="username" placeholder="username"/>
      <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="password"/>
      <button className="LogInButton" onClick={ setDetails }>Log in</Link>
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: Thanks emi, will try tomorrow and let you know if it works

Comment: hmm after replacing my return with yours it is showing  `Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
    in Home (created by Context.Consumer)`

Comment: This is because `isValid` is being considered truthy on its initial value `[]`. Use `false` in its `useState` and ensure the response from server is translated into `true` or `false` (if the server responds with a JSON, evaluate the correct value inside it).

Comment: It also means your are making an extra initial request to server with empty user/pw. You probably want to fix this too.

Comment: cheers. I actually complete redid it and removed UseEffect. Then added your conditional redirect and now it works like a charm. Also used form and input combo rather than button. New code can be seen under UPDATED.

Comment: You can use the event's `event.target.value` to stop doing DOM queries to retrieve form's values: `onChange={ event => setUsername(event.target.value) }` (and similar with PW). This way you can also remove `id`s from your JSX/DOM.